# Inside class access to outside class variable?

Tags: python, class

I have classes: `C1` and `C2`, a `C1` instance is created inside `C2`, and some `C1` class functions also need variables from `C2`. Although I can move those function inside `C2`, it would be a little bit messy. Is there any way to import C2's variable into the test_func in C1?

C1_class.py:

```
class C1():
    C1_a = 1
    C1_b = 2

    def test_func(self):
        result = self.C1_a*C2.C2_a+self.C1_b*C2.C2_b
        return result
```

C2_class.py

```
import C1 
class C2():
    C2_a = 1
    C2_b = 2
    C1_sample = C1_class.C1()

C2_sample = C2()
print(C2_sample.C1_sample.test_func)
```

Comment: Please post the *desired* code as the outcome of your own effort to solve it.  Try improving it yourself first.

Comment: What, exactly, isn't working?

Comment: sorry guys it's actually working...

Comment: what if these two are in different files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing the *function* isn't what you want, I think ... you want the functional value, correct?

```
print(C2_sample.C1_sample.test_func() )
#                                  ^^  forgot the parentheses
```

Output:

```
5
```

The problem is not that they're in two different files.  It's that you haven't called the function.

```
test_func
```

is the function descriptor, giving you access to that object.
It's attributes include the parameters, etc.

```
test_func()
```

is a call to the function, returning a value.

Comment: Hello, I just edited the code... It doesn't work if these two are in different python files?

Comment: Sorry for the late thanks, that's really helpful